flutterfire configure returns "zsh: command not found: flutterfire" on Mac
I'm trying to connect Firebase to my Flutter project.

I've installed the Flutterfire CLI, and export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin" in my terminal, but when I perform:
flutterfire configure --project=milra-61bdb

it gives me zsh: command not found: flutterfire.
I've restarted VC code as well as my computer, which was a common solution in the other answers to this question.
Any idea what else I can try?

try once opening terminal manually from project root folder instead of vs code


Open a terminal and type vim .zshrc
Press i to start editing
Add export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
Press esc then : and finally wq

Changes to the ~/.zshrc file will not take effect in the Terminal until you've quit and restarted the terminal. After that you can use the flutterfire CLI globally
